# How to remove a prefix name from every table name in a mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a joomla mysql database with a table name prefix of "jos_" on all of my table names. But I would like to remove it from all of my tables. I understand how to rename each table, one at a time, but I have 600 tables. Is there an easy to run a sql query to do this.

If someone has a solution, could you please post the exact sql query I can use?

Comment: I hope that there are no internal dependencies here!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can generate the necessary statements with a single query:

```
select 'RENAME TABLE ' || table_name ||  ' TO ' || substr(table_name, 5) ||';'
from information_schema.tables
```

Save the output of that query to a file and you have all the statements you need.

Or if that returns `0`s and `1`s rather the statemenets, here's the version using `concat` instead:

```
select concat('RENAME TABLE ', concat(table_name, concat(' TO ', concat(substr(table_name, 5), ';'))))
from information_schema.tables;
```

Comment: Pretty sure you were looking for `concat`, not `||` (doesn't work my copy of MySQL, anyway).

Comment: `||` works for me (but I'm running my installation in ANSI mode)

Comment: I added the `concat` version for people for whom `||` returns `0`s and `1`s.

Answer (score 19):

1. In phpmyadmin **select all tables** of your database.
2. From the dropdown 'With selected:' choose **'Replace table prefix'**
3. Set **from->to** replacement.
4. DONE

Comment: OMG. This solution is awesome. That's how you do it

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own stored procedure to rename your tables, with that you don't need to open an external editor everything will be done on the server:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE rename_tables( IN db CHAR(255), IN srch CHAR(255), IN rplc CHAR(255) )
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE from_table CHAR(255);
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=db;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    FETCH cur1 INTO from_table;
    SET @to_table = REPLACE(from_table, srch, rplc);

    IF from_table != @to_table THEN
      SET @rename_query = CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ', db, '.', from_table, ' TO ', @to_table, ';');

      PREPARE stmt FROM @rename_query;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END IF;

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
END//
delimiter ;
```

Usage:

```
CALL rename_tables('test', 'jos_', '');
```

**Update:** This was my first MySQL stored procedure and I ran into the *6 years* old [bug #5967](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5967) which was quite annoying, your variable names must be different from the field names, because if they aren't you'll get `NULL` values in your variables.

So be aware of that if you decide to write a MySQL stored procedure.