# DBA Setting in MySQL to avoid schema name as prefix for every table

Tags: mysql

I have about 200 tables that are prefixed with the schema name- hram_whsql.   if i alter from MySQL workbench it still persists. If I create a table the new table has a prefix. I want to get rid of this prefix for all the tables.

Thanks!

Manish

Comment: Does not [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404158/how-to-remove-a-prefix-name-from-every-table-name-in-a-mysql-database) help you?

Comment: if I create a new schema called foo create a table bar the name takes the following structure foo.bar