# How to remove a prefix name from every table name in specific MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, alter-table

All tables in specific `MySQL` database, for example `my_db`, start with a prefix which its length is `17` character. I want to remove prefix from name of all tables. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

improved hasanghaforian's answer...
removed extra concat functions.. still produces same output

```
select concat('RENAME TABLE ', table_name, ' TO ' , substr(table_name,18) , ' ; ' ) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'my_db';
```

Answer (score 1):

I added `where table_schema = 'my_db'` to the statement that is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6404187/1043882) to get statements for renaming all tables in `my_db` database, instead of renaming all tables of all databases in MySQL server instance:

```
select concat('RENAME TABLE ', concat(table_name, concat(' TO ', concat(substr(table_name, 18), ';')))) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'my_db';
```

Pay attention that the length of prefix was `17` and I used `18` in `substr` command.